# How to add folder to existing user [proftpd]

Tags: root, ftp, useradd

As we know we can add folder to user using `useradd user -p user_passwd -d /home/ftp/user_dir/ -s /bin/false` but how to add folder to existing user, for example /home/ftp/root for root ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you don't add, you change home directory.

```
usermod -d /home/ftp/root root
```

if you want to move existing files, use this:

```
usermod -d /home/ftp/root -m root
```

**Allowing root to access via FTP it not good practice, it's security hole.**

Even if this, I would rather recommend to create symlink to target folder from existing directory.